# Reading a URL page with the help of Threads - Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, url, android-asynctask

I was being a bit naive, thinking I can read webpages the same way as you do in Java, but apparently you need to use threads or `AsyncTask`. Which I have no prior experience in and are proving to be hassle.

I've read http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html (3. point) which I semi understand but when I try to implement into my problem it all falls apart.

Here's my problem:

1. I need to read from an URL, it's a RSS feed.
2. Parse it all together
3. Insert it into `ListView` (arrayadapter)

This is my `AsyncTask` class, that I tried to recreate. I just want it to return a buffered reader, or the whole page but it's always null.

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, BufferedReader> {

     @Override
     protected BufferedReader doInBackground(String... urls) {
         BufferedReader bs;
         URL url = null;
         try {
             url = new URL(urls[0]);
         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         try {
             bs = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
             return bs;
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(BufferedReader result) {
        br = result;
    }
}

public RSS() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    DownloadWebPageTask dl = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    dl.execute(new String[]     {"http://www.promet.si/dc/PROMET.ROADEVENTS.PP.RSS.SL"});
}
```

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I don't fully understand posts explaining this and I have to solve this problem. I just need the page's content in any way shape or form. (Can be a `String`, `BufferedReader`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) throws IOException {
        URLConnection connection = new URL(urls[0]).openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()),"UTF-8");
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String buffer;
        while ((buffer = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(buffer);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Use the buffered reader to read line by line in the background thread, and make it return string.

Comment: That does work, but how do I  use this result outside of AsyncTask, I try to get the result from PostExecute, and print it out after i call  

dl.execute(new String[] {"http://www.promet.si/dc/PROMET.ROADEVENTS.PP.RSS.SL"});

and its empty. I think the timing is wrong.